# Nuxt | When viewing source code in browser some of HTML tags showing only inside JavaScript tags

Tags: javascript, vue.js, seo, nuxt.js

If you take a look at this page http://manvanstage.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ and right click on it and choose "View page source" you will find for example the text "100s Man With Van Providers" inside `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of inside inside an HTML tag.

These tags are sent by the back-end API to the front-end (Nuxt.js/vue.js)

I tried to use Vue.js lifecycle `created` and `mounted`.

What I'm doing wrong?

I know this is bad for SEO.

**Update:**

- Part of this web page I used `no-ssr`. Do you think this maybe the cause of the issue?
- I used `npm run build` and deploy the application on Node.js severer.

Comment: do you have npm (or yarn) running on the server or did you upload the nuxt generated pages (with `npm run nuxt generate` (or `yarn nuxt generate`) )

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet I use Node.js server `npm run build`

Answer (score 1):

maybe you should check mode property is correctly set 'universal' in nuxt.config.js

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode/

**Update:**

I think it is because you fetch data in created or mounted so they are still not server-side rednder

if you want show something content in source to imporve SEO then fetch your data in `asyncData()`

example:

before

```
created(){
  this.getSomethingFromAPI()
}
```

after

```
asyncData(){
  this.getSomethingFromAPI()
}
```

Comment: The mode is correct, maybe it's `no-ssr` tag I used.